# Failed Windows Update, Understanding Rollbacks

Tags: windows-7, updates, wsus

A little bit of background, I work as an network administrator for an investment banking company, if a computer isn't working then the directors consider that to be losing money, this means that is a important that everything is available to run at 6AM when the sales team start, even though the IT team don't start till 7am.

TL;DR Computers must work immediately at 6am, IT start at 7am.

So when we run windows updates, sometimes the updates fail and have to be rolled back, they only seem to roll back when a user attempts to login.

How can I get a failed update to roll back immediately after failing?

Comment: How many computers in your company?

Comment: we have about 40 computers

Comment: I'm just racking my brain as to how you'd get around this that didn't involve a complicated startup script that would check your Event Viewer (or update history) to see any failures and rollback as necessary once the updates have "restarted" your machine automatically...

Comment: Use WSUS and take control of when the updates apply.

Comment: We have to apply the updates out of hours, i was thinking forcing all the computers to login and logout at like 4am, this would give time for the updates to roll back, could this be the solution?